# I'm having trouble adding information to a class

Tags: c#, class

In C# I have an AddressBook class and within that class I have a list of Contacts.  I have a Contact class which inherits from my abstract Person class (it has Name, Sex, DOB).  BUT I want each contact to be able to have contact info, so I created another class called ContactInfo (phone number, address, city). I'm having an issue with figuring out how to attach the ContactInfo properties (number, address, etc) to each Contact that the user decides to input into the AddressBook.  Below is my Contact class and my ContactInfo class:

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    public ContactInfo info, newInfo;
    public Contact()
    { }

    public ContactInfo GetContactInfo()
    {
        var info = new ContactInfo();
        return info.GatherContactInfo();
    }

    //public ContactInfo Info { get; set; }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set;}
    public Contact contact;

    public ContactInfo()
    { }
        public ContactInfo GatherContactInfo()
        {
            var newInfo = new ContactInfo();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter their phone number:");
            string phoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            newInfo.PhoneNumber = StorePhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter their address:  ");
            string address = Console.ReadLine();
            newInfo.Address = StoreAddress(address);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter city:  ");
            string city = Console.ReadLine();
            newInfo.City = StoreCity(city);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter State: ");
            string _state = Console.ReadLine();
            newInfo.State = StoreState(_state);

            return newInfo;
        }
```

Comment: `I'm having an issue` what is the issue? You can't figure out how to design it in a way that makes sense or your implementation here isn't working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You generally want to separate the model from the data entry. So have the user enter the contact details, and create or fill the ContactInfo using the fields entered.

Comment: Is there a reason the additional information isn't stored directly in the `Contact`? ... Or is that that question? I.e., *How does one add fields to a subclass?* (If that's it, the answer is *the same as for any other class.*)

Comment: If I kept Contact and ContactInfo as separate classes, is there a way to link a Contact instance to it's proper ContactInfo and vice versa?  Could I extract contactinfo from the List<Contact> Contacts???

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to rethink your code structure. Why would you have `AddressBook` contain info that `ContactInfo` is going to contain?

Why not have Contact contain everything and have that be a list within `AddressBook`?

```
// obviously pseudocode
AddressBook {
   Name
   OwnerName
   ...
   List(of Contacts)
   MethodToGetContactInfo()
}
```

You don't want to store the same data multiple times if you can avoid it (you almost always can with good design). I'd go back to the drawing board before you get too far into it that it's going to take a lot more work than it needs to.

Comment: I agree with Yatrix and would rather put all of the contact information into one Contact class.  I’m learning and my friend was trying to teach me the difference between “is a” and “has a” relationships, i.e.:  A contact is a person, a contact has contact information and thusly separated Contact from ContactInfo which has gotten me to the current situation.

Comment: Flup, you also mentioned separating the model from the data entry by creating or filling the ContactInfo using the fields entered.  I understand encapsulating the ContactInfo class to only know about it's characteristics, but could someone post an example of taking the user input and filling the ContactInfo fields

Comment: Also, if I were to keep Contact and ContactInfo in separate classes, how could I link each Contact to having it's own ContactInfo?  My failed attempts above clearly did not work.

Comment: @user2359626 just fill them in the constructor of contactinfo or through public properties. MyContact.MyContactInfo.myProperty = "my value";